# Does a Super Mario Galaxy 100% Speedrun Count if I don't get a star with Luigi?

Tags: speedrun, super-mario-galaxy

OK, so I have been wanting to get into super Mario galaxy speedrunning for a while now. I know that for a 100 percent all stars are required. However, I also know that there is an extra star you can get by 100% the game with Luigi. I can't imagine that this would be included in a 100 percent speedrun. Is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [speedrun.com](https://www.speedrun.com/smg1#242_Stars), there's a category for 120 stars and another for 242 stars.

120 category rules:

> Start timing when selecting "Play This File," and end timing when touching the final Grand Star. Get all 120 Stars, then beat Bowser's Galaxy Reactor.

242 category rules:

> Start timing when selecting "Play This File." Timing stops once you have collected 121 stars as Luigi and as Mario on the same file